# How remove a character from the middle of a string in excel

Tags: excel

I have 1900 codes (rows) (eg V933) that correspond to surgical operation types. I need to convert them all from V93.3 to V933   - ie remove a period after the first three characters. 
I have seen solutions for prefixing and appending but not in the middle of a string.

Comment: `=mid(A1, 1, 3) & "." & mid(A1, 4, 1)` should do the trick

Comment: @JNevill, I think you mean something like `=MID(A1, 1, 3) & MID(A1, 5, 10000)` ?

Comment: @capnahab, could there be other periods in the string, either within the first 3 characters or after the 4th character?

Comment: Yes. I read that backwards. Definitely feel like `Substitute()` is the better option here (as long as no other periods appear sin the string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about substitute(), like this:

[image]

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")
```

Comment: Maybe use `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","",1)`, in case there is more than one period in the string